# For Customer id, match event id from another dataframe using Customer id and application date

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
dataframe <- data.frame(Cust_ID = c("1","2","2","3","1","3","1","1","2","2"), 
                        App_date = as.Date(c("2023-05-01","2023-05-02","2023-05-03","2023-05-06","2023-04-30","2023-04-04","2023-05-30","2023-05-31","2023-05-30","2023-05-31")),
                        Product = c("AA","AA","BB","AA","CC","BB","AA","AA","CC","BB"),
                        event_id = NA)

dataframe2 <- data.frame(Cust_ID = c("1","3","1","3","1","1"), 
                        App_date = as.Date(c("2023-05-01","2023-05-06","2023-04-30","2023-04-04","2023-05-30","2023-05-31")),
                        Product = c("AA","AA","CC","BB","AA","AA"),
                        Age = c(50,32,50,32,50,50)
                        event_id = c(2,4,2,5,NA,NA))
```

The resultant that i want should look like this:

```
resultant_data <- data.frame(Cust_ID = c("1","2","2","3","1","3","1","1","2","2"), 
                        App_date = as.Date(c("2023-05-01","2023-05-02","2023-05-03","2023-05-06","2023-04-30","2023-04-04","2023-05-30","2023-05-31","2023-05-30","2023-05-31")),
                        Product = c("AA","AA","BB","AA","CC","BB","AA","AA","CC","BB"),
                        event_id = c(2,NA,NA,4,2,5,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: Could you describe in words what you are looking to do?

Comment: I want to add event_id in dataframe by using Cust_ID and App_date from dataframe2

Answer (score 0):

use `dplyr::row_update` or `dplyr::rows_patch`:

```
library(dplyr)
dataframe$event_id <- as.numeric(dataframe$event_id)

rows_update(dataframe,dataframe2,by=c("Cust_ID","App_date","Product"))
   Cust_ID   App_date Product event_id
1        1 2023-05-01      AA        2
2        2 2023-05-02      AA       NA
3        2 2023-05-03      BB       NA
4        3 2023-05-06      AA        4
5        1 2023-04-30      CC        2
6        3 2023-04-04      BB        5
7        1 2023-05-30      AA       NA
8        1 2023-05-31      AA       NA
9        2 2023-05-30      CC       NA
10       2 2023-05-31      BB       NA
```

Updates:
You can mutate empty columns (Age in this case):

```
rows_update(dataframe %>%mutate(Age=NA_real_),dataframe2,by=c("Cust_ID","App_date","Product"))

   Cust_ID   App_date Product event_id Age
1        1 2023-05-01      AA        2  50
2        2 2023-05-02      AA       NA  NA
3        2 2023-05-03      BB       NA  NA
4        3 2023-05-06      AA        4  32
5        1 2023-04-30      CC        2  50
6        3 2023-04-04      BB        5  32
7        1 2023-05-30      AA       NA  50
8        1 2023-05-31      AA       NA  50
9        2 2023-05-30      CC       NA  NA
10       2 2023-05-31      BB       NA  NA
```

Comment: It gives the following error:
Error in `rows_patch()`:
! All columns in `y` must exist in `x`.

Comment: The answer is updated